OpenCV returns some values from negative positions
I try on OpenCV for Java (org.openpnp:opencv:4.7.0-0) and have Mat (2x2), created by  val mat = Mat(2, 2, CvType.CV_8UC3)

Getting pixels from it by means of mat[0, 0] ( = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]).  It's ok
Getting pixels out of range mat[0, 2] ( = null). It's also ok
Getting pixels from negative positions mat[0, -1000] ( = [114.0, 47.0, 84.0]).

Why OpenCV returns some array instead of null or an exception? Where are these numbers from?
example:
package example;

import nu.pattern.OpenCV;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        OpenCV.loadLocally();
        Mat mat = new Mat(2, 2, CvType.CV_8UC3);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mat.get(0, -1000)));
        mat.release();
    }
}

I noticed that the bug is more repeatable in debug mode, in run mode it returns [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] more often

does java even support indexing like [0, 0]?

actially it is kotlin. You can use mat.get(y,x). The result would be the same

I believe this is a bug in the implementation of the Java bindings. It checks for out-of-bounds indices with (me->rows<=row || me->cols<=col) (where me is the source Mat), but the indices are signed integers. Therefore negative indices will get through unnoticed. This seems to correlate with your observations -- mat[0, 2] is not OK, and signals failure by returning null. mat[0, -1000] is probably just lucky by touching some memory the process already owns, so you don't end up with a segfault.

Try it with some very large negative indices for both row and column. Might be worth filing a bug in the OpenCV GitHub repo. A proper [mcve] would be useful for both (e.g. I haven't really written much Java since the beginning of this century, so it would would help if I could reproduce this without needing to write a whole new class... or whatever it is you do these days... and just focus on getting it compiled ;)).

Thanks. If I type some very large negative indices (mat.get(Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE)) the application crashes withA fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Dan's conclusion makes sense to me. It's a bug. Please file an issue. Feel free to link to this question for context, or make sure the findings (link to java/generator/src/cpp/Mat.cpp and such) make their way into the issue description.
